# How to add transparency to a HTML table using IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, transparency

Im working on some html stuff at the moment but have come across a little problem. I have an image which uses hotspots to create a rollover effect, within the rollover are I also have an html table but when I rollover the hotspot area turns green(as it should) but the table remains white.
is there a way I can make this table transparent?

as you can see below I have commented out what I had tried previously(filter:alpha)

code for table is...

```
<div style="position:absolute; left: 709px; top: 353px; background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px none #000000;">
<table width="50" border="0" ><!-- style="filter:alpha(opacity=80);"-->
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center" style="font:'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-size:10px">Lvl.20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25"><IMG id="t11" style="cursor: hand; WIDTH: 24px; HEIGHT: 22px;" name=disp alt="Lvl.20" src="../../Icons/circle_cancel.png"></td>
<td width="25"><IMG id="t12" style="cursor: hand; WIDTH: 24px; HEIGHT: 22px;" name=disp alt="Lvl.20" src="../../Icons/circle_cancel.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Css-Tricks.com:

```
.transparent {
        /* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
        /* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
        width: 100%; 

        /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
        /* ...but not required as filter works too */
        /* should come BEFORE filter */
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

        /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
        /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);

        /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
        -moz-opacity:0.5;

        /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

        /* Modern!
        /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
        /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
        opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This is for all browsers!

Comment: i've put the above into my css then changed the class of the table to transparent but it doesn't seem to have an effect.
<table class="transparent" width="50" border="0" >

is there a way to put this straight into html instead of changing the css file as im not entirely sure about css just yet (fairly new to web editing)

Comment: Your best bet when coding is to separate your styling from your content from your function. It's much easier to make and keep track of changes when they are separate components. The code works for me. I placed the class on the table and gave the background a color so I could tell if it really is transparent (I used background-color:#CC3; on the body selector).

Comment: I've got it working now, had the wrong css sheet at first. you sir are a gentleman & a scholar. Thank you